# Determinant of tensor product of matrices under simultaneous diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have an exercise in linear algebra as follows: Assume that $A_{mn}=B_m\otimes B_n+C_m\otimes C_n$ where subscripts determine the size of (square) matrices. Assume that we can diagonalise simultaneously $B_n$ and $C_n$ by a matrix $U_n$ so that $U_nB_nU_n^{-1}=D_n$ and $U_nC_nU_n^{-1}=E_n$ are diagonal matrices. Prove that $$\det A_{mn}=\det(B_m\otimes D_n+C_m\otimes E_n).$$

I have no idea how to do that. Someone can help me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

One can write
\begin{eqnarray*}
(I_m\otimes U_n)\cdot A_{mn}&=&(I_m\otimes U_n)\cdot(B_m\otimes B_n+C_m\otimes C_n)\\
&=&(I_m\cdot B_m)\otimes(U_n\cdot B_n)+(I_m\cdot C_m)\otimes(U_n\cdot C_n)\\
&=&(B_m\cdot I_m)\otimes(D_n\cdot U_n)+(C_m\cdot I_m)\otimes(E_n\cdot U_n)\\
&=&(B_m\otimes D_n)\cdot(I_m\otimes U_n)+(C_m\otimes E_n)\cdot(I_m\otimes U_n)\\
&=&(B_m\otimes D_n+C_m\otimes E_n)\cdot (I_m\otimes U_n),
\end{eqnarray*}
which implies our equality.